# How to get only the pub part of gpg --list-public-keys?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, gpg, duplicity

Okay, there is probably a better way to phrase this question. I am writing a script to configure my web servers on the first boot, but I hit a snag when generating the GPG key that will be used to encrypt backups with duplicity.

I am [using this](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html#Unattended-GPG-key-generation) to generate the key without user interaction, but I need a way to get only the number under pub to throw on a file that will be used by duplicity later on the script.

**I need this:**

```
jamespond@penelope:~$ gpg --list-public-keys
/home/jamespond/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2018-11-10 [SC] [expires: 2020-11-09]
      8304C92D7F77938BCE05A1619FC07FF505D443D3
uid           [ultimate] James Pond <root@madpony.co>
sub   rsa3072 2018-11-10 [E] [expires: 2020-11-09]
```

**To become this:**

```
jamespond@penelope:~$ gpg --list-public-keys | somecommand
8304C92D7F77938BCE05A1619FC07FF505D443D3
```

Is that possible? I looked at GPG's man page and it doesn't seem like there is a command for that, so I am guessing I would need to pipe *--list-public-keys* to sed? But I have no idea what regular expression I would need to use to get just that piece of the puzzle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of gpg do you have? When I looked at the man page, under `--list-public-keys`, it said exactly what to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Using GPG 2.2.8. Problem with `--with-colons` is that it also does not give me a readable format. My understanding is that duplicity only accept "8304C92D7F77938BCE05A1619FC07FF505D443D3" as input for `--encryption-key` (but I could be wrong).

Comment: That's the wrong field. The field is listed on the `pub` line, not the `uid` line.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ah, I was looking at this the wrong way. Using the name on the `uid` line is accepted by duplicity (so `--encryption-key="James Pond"`). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will want to use the `--with-colons` output mode for scripting. Then, to grab only the fingerprints of the public keys, I used `sed` to narrow down to only the `pub` part and `cut` to get to the 10th field of the `fpr` field:

```
gpg --list-public-keys --with-colons \
    | sed -ne '/^pub:/,/^fpr:/ { /^fpr:/ p }' \
    | cut -d: -f10
```

If you have multiple keys, it will print each of them on a line of its own.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! :)